# Search by url parameter in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, search

I have view:

```
   <?php echo form_open_multipart('search/item');?>
    <input type='text' name='search' value="<?php echo set_value('search')?>">
    <input type="submit" name="search_submit" value='Suchen'>
   </form>
```

My controller looks like but not working:

```
    public function item($search=''){

        if($search == '' &&  $this->input->post("search") != ""){
            $search = urlencode($search);
            header("Location:".site_url()."/search/item/$search");
        }

        $search = urldecode($search);
        echo "suchen fur".$search;
    }
```

How to make controller that gets search text by url like mysite.com/search/item/search+text and shows result?

Comment: This is a very common feature. Have you looked in [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)?

Comment: Think I couldn't explain my problem, I understand MVC but, look at my controller. At first I recieve search text by post, then I redirect to mysite.com/search/item/search+text. But it not working

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the [URI Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

```
$search_term = $this->uri->segment(3);
// for mysite.com/search/item/search+text
// $search_term would be "search text"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->helper('url'); 
$search_term = $this->uri->segment(3);
redirect("/search/item/" . $search_term);
```